# How to intercept session invalid or timeout in springboot?.

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-security, spring-boot

When I restart my app service my url is same as previous and when i click on some action or refresh then it redirect to login page and after successful login it gives error hhtpgetmethod access.

What should I do when my session timeout or service restart it automatically redirect to my login page.

My security configuration is

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "contactus", "aboutus", "gallery", "signup").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
            // .antMatchers("/user/reset-password").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/reset-password-change").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/autologin")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPER') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/user/delete").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").antMatchers("/user/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPER') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").antMatchers("/super/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPER')");
    http.formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/user/home").loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().csrf().and().rememberMe()
            .key(applicationSecret).tokenValiditySeconds(31536000);

}
```

Comment: Do you want the user to be automatically redirected to login page when session timeouts without him performing any action? AFAIK, a HttpRequest is required in order to perform a redirection.

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBiker Not sure how can we manage. but my requirement is after session out start new request because when I refresh it asks for login and then gives error like method does not support get or `httpmethodsupport` error. When I use my home then works fine for other request.

Comment: Then, try to manage to fix the error instead of changing your application behaviour. It seems to suit better.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Like When I tried to edit an record http://app/edit/1 and after that i restart service or my session timed out. In this case when i refresh url it ask login and then gives error. Is this not session problem ?. Is this my method problem?. When I click home and login than it works fine.